# Windows 8.1 crashes repeatedly

Tags: windows

since i upgraded from windows 8 to 8.1 my system has crashed repeatedly giving me errors like this
1.MEMORY MANAGEMENT caused by ntoskrnl.exe+14dca0
2.PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA caused by vwififlt.sys+3cd19c
3.MEMORY MANAGEMENT caused by tcpipreg.sys+fe71b700
What can i do to solve this problem?????
i have used the driver verifier and still nothing has changed,did a clean install of windows 8.1 still got this errors

Comment: The two files you mentioned `vwififlt.sys` and `tcpipreg.sys` are related to your *Wireless Network Card*. Try disabling Wireless Connection and hardwire your system to router. Browse for sometime and see if BSOD will occur.

Comment: Does this happen within a minimal boot configuration? Does this happen while in Safe Mode? Have you made sure **ALL** device drivers are updated and specifically support Windows 8.1? You should also rule out a memory problem so run [MemTest86](http://www.memtest.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In your crash report - you mention 2 files:

- vwififlt.sys - [Info on this file](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/Virtual_WiFi_Filter_Driver-26951.html)
- tcpipreg.sys - [Info on this file](http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/process.pl?p=tcpipreg.sys)

These files are both related to networking as evidenced by the links above.

This indicates that the problem may be with either your wired - or more likely your wireless network adapter (assuming you have one)

If you have not done so already - try the following:

- Reboot into safe mode and see if the problem persists
- Reinstall all the latest drivers - preferably signed/verified ones for your OS (specifically networking, chipset)
- System restore to a point in time when when you had working functionality.

That said, your answer states that you have already done a complete reinstall of your operating system - which would mean that sys restore won't work, but the others may if you used the wrong drivers twice.

Other things to try are:

- Disable each network adapter in turn and see if the problem goes away with a specific device.  This will narrow down the device at fault
- try updating the device drivers through control panel > device manager > right click wifi card > update driver and get the latest windows signed drivers instead of the manufacturer drivers.
- Replace your wireless card

Hopefully this will help a bit.